# Why am I getting a segmentation fault (core Dumped) in a program to encrypt string?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, c-strings, string-literals

I'm currently learning C programming. This is the C code to encrypt a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void encrypt(char *message){           // Here message is a character pointer - array
    //char c;
    while(*message){
        *message = *message ^31;
        message++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *msg = {"Hello Howdy?"};
    encrypt(msg);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting 'Segmentation fault(core dumped)' as the output. It compiles though.

Comment: You can't change a string literal. Use `char msg[]` and it'll be stored as a character array which you'll be able to manipulate.

Comment: @iBug doesn't , char *msg  same as char msg[0] ?

Comment: Literal strings in C are not modifiable, they are in essence *read only*. You need to create your own array (as suggested by @iBug) like `char msg[] = "Hello Howdy?";`.